# Nginx authentication with auth_request module

Tags: php, authentication, nginx, auth-request

i have installed nginx with auth_request module enabled, but i have a problem when i am trying to setup the authentication. I want to authenticate through a php script, when a user makes request to this location, then the nginx request to a php file and if the response will be 2xx then authentication true if the response will be 4xx then authentication failed.

This is what i made for now and it is working perfect this thing but i dont know how to pass arguments on the php file like username password for example: 
http://example.com/live/index.php?username=test&password=password

Here is the configuration which is working without these arguments.

```
location /live {
         auth_request /http_auth;
    }

    location /http_auth {
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/login.php;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 11):

The trick here is to combine `auth_basic` and `auth_request`, here is an example:

```
location = /api {
        satisfy any;
        auth_basic "Restricted Access";
        auth_basic_user_file "/usr/local/nginx/htpasswd";
        auth_request /auth;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api.html;
    }

    location = /auth {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
       proxy_pass_request_body off;
       proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
       proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }
```

You will notice that auth_basic_user_file is present and you probably don't want it but you can leave a blank file, the **`satisfy any`** will accept any success, `auth_basic` will fail but will also set the user and password in the HTTP Headers that are forwarded to your backend script where you can handle them accordingly.

Comment: hey, can you document  the code a little bit more i've been running into the same wall using a python script instead of php

Comment: Is there some specific part that is not clear, @Newbie ? The idea here is: The request will come and reach /api, there the auth_basic module will mark it as invalid according to the "/usr/local/nginx/htpasswd" file, because it is empty. However, due to the satisfy any it will also send a request to /auth where you can handle it properly in your python script, since it is doing an "OR" operation(any) it will be false OR true making it work. That is a workaround because the auth_basic demands a auth_basic_user_file. Do you have your python back-end properly configured on nginx ?

Comment: I tried your trick but the login info is hashed by auth_basic when i look it up in the headers in my python script, is there another way to pass it without hashing it?

Comment: basic authentication does not hash, it is just a base64 encoding, you can decode it back. Try this: encodedString.decode('base64')

Comment: that worked thanks! i have futher question is there a way to contact you?

Comment: Sorry to digging out so old thread. I have problem. I want to use this above trick.. to redirect user and pass from basic auth to auth_request and there handle authentication in my other service. But when I give both auth_basic and auth_request, nginx seems to follow auth_request ignoring auth_basic. Why something like this can happen?

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue as hohel. Nginx seems to go straight to auth_request bypassing auth_basic altogether. According to the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) auth_request can be used in conjunction with auth_basic... @PedroSena can you comment if this is still working for you?

Comment: Are you both putting the two "auth_basic" statements before the auth_request ?

Comment: @PedroSena Yes auth_basic is before auth_request.

Comment: @PedroSena I opened a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301559/nginx-with-auth-request-and-auth-basic) as well, but haven't gotten any attention

Comment: I'm running into the same issue; with the above configuration the user is never prompted for login details the and auth_request is made first.