# Nginx satisfy any not working in correct order

Tags: authentication, nginx, proxy, basic-authentication

I have problem with nginx. What I want to achieve is to fake Basic Authentication like in this article: [Nginx authentication with auth_request module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299623/nginx-authentication-with-auth-request-module)
But unfortunately when I do this "trick", nginx seems to go straight to the auth_request, totally ignoring auth_basic. Did anyone have this problem?

Regards,
hohel

@Edit

It seems that satisfy start with auth_request instead of auth_basic. Is there some directive like

```
Satisfy any but first auth_basic;
```

@Edit 2

My code look something like this:

```
location / {
 satisfy any;
 auth_basic "Blabla";
 auth_basic_user_file /path/to/empty/htpasswd/file;
 auth_request /auth;
}
location = /auth {
 Set headers and pass them to authentication service
}
```

@Edit 3
I'm still getting 500 internal error (because this from autentication service i've got access forbidden since no data is sent there), but i can see that in header of this page is:

```
WWW-Autenticate: "Basic realm="Blabla""
```