# Nginx with auth_request and auth_basic

Tags: authentication, nginx

I can't seem to get this to work. According to the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) they can be used together.

Nginx Version: 1.10.3 --with-http_auth_request_module

```
location ~ ^/test(/.*|$) {
    satisfy any;
    auth_basic "test";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
    auth_request auth.php;
}
```

My `.htpasswd` is blank. I want the username/password input in the basic form to be passed to my auth.php file. With this config when accessing /test I can see the subrequest made directly to auth.php. It never does a basic auth prompt. If I comment out `auth_request auth.php` the basic auth prompt does show. The doc does say to use `satisfy any` when using multiple auth modules.

There is an exact similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299623/nginx-authentication-with-auth-request-module) with an answer, but it doesn't seem to work.

If anyone has gotten this to work can you help me out here?

Comment: Hey Chris, try to set a "location" like I did in the other question and also use full paths just to exclude the possibility that this relative path is wrong.

Comment: Tried with `location = /test {` and I get the same results. Tries auth_request and ignores auth_basic.

Comment: @PedroSena Do you have a working config of this setup?

Comment: Not anymore @Chris, I used this long time ago(my answer to the other thread was from 2014)

Comment: @PedroSena No problem, can't hurt to ask...